# In language C. How to get the lvalue identifier of a previously declared variable?

Tags: c, pointers, lvalue

My purpose is to create the function `void print_chars(char *imp)` to print the elements of a character string. The string is passed to the function by reference, using a pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define len(x, y) sizeof(x) / sizeof(y)

void print_chars(char*);
/* Function to print the characters of a string passed by reference to
 * the function.*/

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
/* Definition of the string and its characteristics. */
/* The "lvalue" of the string is "m_str". */ 
  char m_str[] = "123456\n89 ab";
  int length_a = len(m_str, m_str[0]);
  
/* Let's point to the string to print it*/
  char *imprimatur = m_str;
  print_chars(imprimatur);
  
  return 0;
}
void print_chars(char *imp)
{
  unsigned int i = 1;
  char *c;
  for (c = imp; *c != '\0'; c++, i++)
    printf("xxx[%d] = %c\n", i, *c);
/*          ^ How to write here the original name of the lvalue 
 * originally assigned outside the funcion? */
}
```

This is a sample of the output:

xxx[1] = 1

xxx[2] = 2

...

And this is the expected output:

m_str[1] = 1

m_str[2] = 2

...

Is there any function in C that allows me to obtain the characteristics of a previously declared variable, for example its lvalue?

Thank you!

Comment: You're misusing the word "lvalue". No, there's no way to do it.

Comment: `void print_chars(char *name, char *imp) { /* ... */ printf("%s[%d] = %c\n", name, i, *c); /* ... */ }` and call it from main as `print_chars("m_str", imprimatur);`. Otherwise, **no, it's impossible to get the source code name of a variable**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C there is no way to get the source codes variable name at run time.

So you have to write some code to achieve your goal. You'll have to extend `print_chars` so that it also takes a name as argument like `void print_chars(char *name, char *imp)` and then call it like `print_chars("m_str", m_str);`

This is both error prone (as you can misspell the name) and annoying (as you need to type it twice). To solve that, you can go for a macro.

Something like:

```
#define PRINT_NAMED_CHARS(var) print_chars(#var, var)

void print_chars(char *name, char *imp)
{
  unsigned int i = 1;
  char *c;
  for (c = imp; *c != '\0'; c++, i++)
    printf("%s[%d] = %c\n", name, i, *c);
}


int main()
{
  char m_str[] = "123";
  
  PRINT_NAMED_CHARS(m_str);
  
  char other_str[] = "abc";
  
  PRINT_NAMED_CHARS(other_str);

  return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
m_str[1] = 1
m_str[2] = 2
m_str[3] = 3
other_str[1] = a
other_str[2] = b
other_str[3] = c
```

**BTW**

To me it's kind of wrong to print the index starting from 1 (one). In C the index always start from 0 (zero).